PHP "stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto" when trying to communicate with a Java server through sockets (localhost)
Java Server:
package sslserverexample;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import org.apache.commons.ssl.*;

public class SSLServerExample {
    static SSLServer server;
    static int port=55143;
    static SSLServerSocket ss;
    static SSLSocket s;
    
    static{
        try{
            server = new SSLServer();
            Security.addProvider(new Provider());
            
            String certificateChain = "keystore100yearscert.crt"; //previously, cert.crt
            String privateKey = "keystore100years.key"; //previously, private.key
            char[] password = "".toCharArray();
            KeyMaterial km = new KeyMaterial(certificateChain, privateKey, password); 

            server.setKeyMaterial(km);

            server.setCheckHostname(false); // default setting is "false" for SSLServer
            server.setCheckExpiry(true);    // default setting is "true" for SSLServer
            server.setCheckCRL(true);       // default setting is "true" for SSLServer

            server.addTrustMaterial( TrustMaterial.TRUST_ALL );
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Static block: "+e.getClass().toString()+" : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    private static final String[] protocols = new String[]{"TLSv1.2"};
    private static final String[] cipher_suites = new String[]{"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"};

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("SSL Server Started!");
        
        
            try {
                ss=(SSLServerSocket) server.createServerSocket(port); 
                s=(SSLSocket) ss.accept();
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                s.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
                s.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipher_suites);
                //s.setSoTimeout(2000);

                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                
                //System.out.println("Initializing writers/streams: "+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
                
                String str=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Received: "+str);

                if(str.equals("Hello server!")){
                    String sent="Hello client!";
                    pw.println(sent);
                    System.out.println("Sent: "+sent);
                    pw.flush();
                }
                
                //System.out.println("Read and write: "+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
                
                s.close();
                ss.close();
                //System.out.println("Total time: "+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SSLServerExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SSLServerExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
       
    }
    
    public static String stringToHex(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        byte[] hexChars = new byte[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}

PHP Client:
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$host = 'localhost';
$port = 55143;
$timeout = 30;
$cert = 'cert.pem'; // Path to certificate
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'ssl'=>array(
'verify_peer '=> false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed'=> true,
'local_cert'=> $cert,
'cafile' => $cert,
'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
'ciphers' => 'aes-128-gcm'       
)
));
$message = 'Hello server!';
$result  = '';

if ($socket = stream_socket_client('tlsv1.2://'.$host.':'.$port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context)){
//echo "stream_socket_enable_crypto: ".stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT);
fwrite($socket, $message."\n");
$result = fread($socket,8192);
echo $result;
fclose($socket);
} else {
   echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr\n";
}

?>

OUTPUT in PHP:
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\apache-sites\ssl_socket_test.php on line 29

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tlsv1.2://localhost:55143 (Unknown error) in C:\apache-sites\ssl_socket_test.php on line 29
ERROR: 0 -

I am able to successfully communicate with the Java server using other languages, but not PHP. I tried testing out the whether client program works correctly in Java itself and Qt/C++ and it worked as expected. I used localhost for all these tests.
I even tried generating new encryption keys just to see if they were the problem. There are not many resources I am able find online about PHP SSL socket programming although there are several about unencrypted sockets. I am new to socket programming.
